# Creating simple database for iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, database, ios7

I'm planing to create an app for iOS which will be kind of informative application for public transport in my city. People will enter street name from where they want to get public transport and will get list of buses and minivans, which are traveling by that street.

My problem is that I'm just started developing for iOS and want to find easy method to create a database/table with simple information as streets name and bus numbers that will connected with those streets.

So basically I need to create database/table and an search-box which will be connected to that database.

From where I need to start? Thanks.

p.s. - sorry for my bad english ;)

Comment: One important question: Will this database be solely on the phone, solely on a web server, or some sort of "hybrid"?  Another question: How will the database be updated, and who will do the updating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is quite popular and supplied by Apple.  This lets you manage your table, and allows most standard SQL queries.  You can also link to Core Data if you want to treat your data as objects.

See [the Apple overview](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/data-management.html)

There are many tutorials to build a simple app with a table view using SQLite, e.g. [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app) or [here](http://hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-How-To-Display-SQLite-Data-in-a-UITableView)

I found the Stanford University videos a good way to learn this stuff, e.g. [here on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y01GJ-wtcEI) or there are later versions available in iTunes U.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, for an on-phone database SQLite is the way to go for a full-featured database, or Core Data if you want some "hand holding".  And, of course, if you don't need persistence you can make a pretty good database simply using NSMutableDictionary and maybe a few custom classes.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use CoreData. Its not there to "hand hold" you, its there to provide a complex and optimized ORM interface for the underlying SQLite database-- there are a number of optimizations implemented to improve efficiency. You could pick it up in a night following tutorials and online instructions.